# Progress Bar with FTS4 SQLite3 search

Tags: sqlite, progress-bar, lazarus, fts4

Mint-19.1, Lazarus 1.8.4

I am using SQlite3 and FTS4 text search and it works fine retrieving results in about 15 to 20 seconds for 3.5GB of data file. But, the process hogs everything and I cannot even activate a Progress Bar in Marquee mode. It starts to move the colored block then stops until the search results are returned.

Is there a call-back or something I can use that will allow me to show the user that the thing is busy searching? Just a rolling number in a TLabel.Caption would be OK too.

I found MTProcs.pas wiki that sounded like it might help, but the links all return 404 error.

And, before anyone slaps this as a "Duplicate," I have checked the claimed duplicates but nothing even remotely applies. :)

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/alrieckert/lazarus/blob/master/components/multithreadprocs/mtprocs.pas?

Comment: @MartynA: OK, thanks, that looks like it will do what I need. Much appreciated.